# How can I bring autoParallaxBackground at front, above all sprites?

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine, sprite

I need a autoParallaxBackground that runs over all sprites. Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Comment: that's a bit of an oxymoron isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps to do this.

1. First, set the Z-Index of the parallax layer to something higher than everything else in the scene.  E.g., if your other scene entities are at Z-index 10, set it to 100.  (The numbers don't matter, just the relative numbers.)  This is accomplished by calling the setZIndex() method.
2. Second, tell the scene to sort its child entities.  This is
   accomplished by calling scene.sortChildren().

Comment: @valter-lorran let me know if that worked for you.